# How to disable dashboard summary in Settings app?

Tags: settings

[image: annotated screenshot]

I find the [dashboard conditional summary](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/src/com/android/settings/dashboard/conditional/) infuriating. How can I have it disabled?

I earlier thought disabling the following receivers would help, but to no avail. (Yes, I did verify and reboot post disabling them.)

```
com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.HotspotCondition$Receiver
com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.AirplaneModeCondition$Receiver
com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.DndCondition$Receiver
com.android.settings.dashboard.conditional.CellularDataCondition$Receiver
```

I'm currently using stock Android 10 on OnePlus 6 with Magisk and Riru.

Comment: I vaguely remember having seen a similar question recently, so it might be worth checking with our search engine. Don't remember the phrasing, though – but AFAIR it was about "no SIM card" (OP didn't want to use the phone functionality anyway).

Comment: I don't know Izzy. Before posting this question I did try the search but with the terms "dashboard" and "settings" app for Nougat tags. Didn't find anything relevant so posted my question.

Comment: I couldn't find it either (just checked). I don't think it used the term "dashboard". IIRC it was about a Samsung device, so at that time I wasn't sure if it was talking about some AOSP generic feature or something Samsung special. Well, just thought to mention it – not crying "dupe" or the like :)

Answer (score -2):

Simply swipe from right to left on the conditional summary and it will disappear.

Comment: It's a temporary solution, but a reboot or toggling the corresponding option on and then off will bring it back again. OP made it clear that he want a permanent disable ("not show up for ... settings change").

Comment: I agree with @Andy.

Comment: I mean its the simplest solution I found, and it literally takes less than a second to remove the conditional summary this way, but lemme see if I can find a "permanent" solution.

Comment: Could not find any permanent solution, seems like swiping it is the only way to dismiss the conditional summary

Comment: If only you can prove it.